# How to add multiple values onto the same array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to show information on my page regarding multiple queries, each of them representing project status. To do that, i made a while loop, that adds information to an array.

The problem with that, is that i only show one of the statuses available, only the first one. Here is my code:

```
$exec = mysql_query($queryOntime) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
$exec1 = mysql_query($queryDelayed) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
$exec2 = mysql_query($queryPending) or trigger_error(mysql_error());        

$array_dados = array();

// All chart data
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($exec)||$info1 = mysql_fetch_array($exec1)||$info2 = mysql_fetch_array($exec2)){    
    $array_dados[] = $info; 
    $array_dados[] = $info1;
    $array_dados[] = $info2;                    
}   
return $array_dados;
```

So as you can see, i have 3 queries, and i try adding all of them into an array, yet only one of the $info shows up. Why is that?

EDIT:

I removed the OR and separated my Fetch arrays, yet it still only shows the "Pending" one. Here's how it looks right now:

```
$exec = mysql_query($queryPending) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
$exec1 = mysql_query($queryOntime) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
$exec2 = mysql_query($queryDelayed) or trigger_error(mysql_error());    

$array_dados = array();

//All chart data
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($exec)) 
    $array_dados[] = $info; 

while($info1 = mysql_fetch_array($exec1))
    $array_dados[] = $info1;

while($info2 = mysql_fetch_array($exec2))
    $array_dados[] = $info2;

return $array_dados;
```

Comment: In PHP, subsequent conditions in OR logic won't be evaluated once one loosely evaluates to true, so if your first call to `mysql_fetch_array` returns anything, the others won't be run.

Comment: I see. So i have to use AND?

Comment: Using AND instead will mean that **all** the queries have to return the same number of rows, or all subsequent ones after the first one that returns nothing won't be run (basically the opposite problem to what you have now). Stop trying to force everything into one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this also..

```
$exec = mysql_query($queryOntime) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
$exec1 = mysql_query($queryDelayed) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
$exec2 = mysql_query($queryPending) or trigger_error(mysql_error());        

$array_dados = array();

// All chart data
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($exec) && $info1 = mysql_fetch_array($exec1) && $info2 = mysql_fetch_array($exec2)){    
    $array_dados[] = $info; 
    $array_dados[] = $info1;
    $array_dados[] = $info2;                    
}   
return $array_dados;
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: If you want to make this more than a comment you had better show the OP at least an example of what you mean